# How to save an expo-picker-image file to the server through an AXIOS POST in Expo ReactNative?

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

I try to save the selected image with expo-picker-image through an API with formData using AXIOS, but it doesn't save it and I don't get any type of error.

I want to be able to save the image to my server using Django Rest Framework and be able to see it when responding a 200.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved as followed:

```
let localUri = result.assets[0].uri
let fileName = localUri.split('/').pop()
let match = /\.(\w+)$/.exec(fileName);
let type = match ? `image/${match[1]}` : `image`;

form.append("image", {uri: localUri, name: fileName, type})
```

In the AXIOS headers add : `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`